# Target specific JVM with Kotlin and Gradle

Tags: kotlin, jvm, target

What is the difference between

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

and

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

Will they both achive the same end result in a gradle/Kotlin-library? jvmTarget is for setting which standardlibrary version to use, I understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kotlinOptions.jvmTarget` is used for specifying a version of the JVM standard library used as a dependency for the compilation of JVM-specific Kotlin source sets (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library and [`-bootclasspath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) option of javac).

`java.sourceCompatibility` ensures that .java files are using the specified version of the Java programming language syntax

`java.targetCompatibility` ensures that the generated .class files will be compatible with the specified JVM

So, these options are not equivalent.

Anyway, the modern (since Gradle 6.7+ and Kotlin 1.5.30+) way of defining cross-compilation parameters is a [toolchain](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1530.html#support-for-java-toolchains):

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain {
        (this as JavaToolchainSpec).languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
    }
}

// Or its eqivalent:

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
    }
}
```